# How to select a drop down using protractor?

Tags: protractor

Can any one help me on how to select a drop down in protractor.

Page Object code

```
function selectDropdownbyNum(element, optionNum) {
        if (optionNum) {
            element.all(by.tagName('option')).then(function(options) {
                browser.sleep('5000');
                options[optionNum].click();
                console.log('Desired value selected');
            });
        }
    }

var pageName= function(){
this.selectTier = async function(){
        var Tiers = element(by.xpath(/*element value*/));
        console.log('select silver method');
        browser.sleep(5000);
        selectDropdownbyNum(Tiers,2);
        console.log('value selected');
    };
};
module.exports = new pageName();
```

And Spec is as follows

```
it('select Silver Tier',async function(){
      browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
      console.log('Executing silver tier selection test case');
      await pageName.selectTier()
    });
```

I have tried the above code. I am able to print all the values of the drop down, but am unable to click.

Is their any mistake in the above code.I can print the '`Desired value selected`'. But value was not selected

Comment: It's not good idea to edit your original question as this might make some of the answers completely irrelevant as in this case!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
var Tiers = element(by.xpath(dropDownValue));
Tiers.click();
selectDropdownbyNum(element, optionNum) {
    if (optionNum) {
        element.all(by.tagName('option')).then(function(options) {
            options[optionNum].click();
        });
    }
}
selectDropdownbyNum(Tiers,4)
```

Note:
avoid using Xpath example use :

```
element(by.css('select[formcontrolname="any value according to situation"]'));
```

Comment: Hi Anandu, Thank you for your replay. I have tried the above code, but i am unable to select the dropdown .

Comment: Can you mention the error you are getting when try the code

Comment: you should click the element before calling the function. see the edited answer

Comment: So, you are saying that .First i need to click the drop down and then select the desired value by optionNum. Am i right?

Answer (score 2):

May this will help you for selecting option

element(by.cssContainingText('option','Option value')).click();

or

```
element(by.id('id')).sendKeys("Values from option");
```

this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it, but I suppose it's because of the nested promise you are using inside the for loop. The nature of the promise is to be async, and the for loop is synchronous, which results in the loop complete whyle the very first promise `items[i].getText().then` get's resolved and that's why your click didn't succeed. If you don't need to know the option names, then just remove the nested promise `items[i].getText()` and just execute the click in the loop.